# Question on partial derivative

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, partial-derivative

If $u= \log(\tan x + \tan y)$, prove that 
$$\sin(2x) \, \frac{du}{dx} + \sin(2y) \, \frac{du}{dy} = 2$$.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Have you tried computing the partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes. So far du/dx = cos y/sin(x+y) and du/dy = cos x/sin(x+y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $u = \ln(\tan x + \tan y)$ the derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ are
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx} &= \frac{sec^{2}(x)}{\tan x + \tan y} \\
\frac{du}{dy} &= \frac{sec^{2}(y)}{\tan x + \tan y}.
\end{align}
Now, 
\begin{align}
\sin(2x) \, \frac{du}{dx} + \sin(2y) \, \frac{du}{dy} &= 2 \, \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{\tan x + \tan y} = 2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I had my share of mistakes.